# Capybara request spec DSL and transactional fixtures

Tags: testing, request, rspec2, capybara

There's a new dsl in capybara 1.0.0.rc1 that's very similar to steak. I'm trying to set up a fixture in a background/before section but when I debug the first scenario/example and inspect the database, the fixture set up in the background is gone. I have use_transactional_fixtures set to true, but it's strange that that would matter given that background is an alias for before. What am I doing wrong?

## spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/blueprints")

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    config.before(:all)    { Sham.reset(:before_all)  }
    config.before(:each)   { Sham.reset(:before_each) }
  end 
end 

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
end
```

## teacher_creates_event.rb

```
require 'requests/requests_helper'                                                                     

feature "Teacher creates event" do                                                                     
  background do                                                                                        
    Teacher.make(:username => 'testteacher', :password => 'mypassword')                                
    visit new_user_session_url                                                                         
    fill_in "Username", :with => 'testteacher'                                                         
    fill_in "Password", :with => 'mypassword'                                                          
    click_on "Sign in"                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                  

  scenario "Teacher creates one-time event" do                                                         
    visit studio_calendar_url                                                                          
    click_on "New Event"                                                                               
    fill_in "Title", :with => "Test One Time Event"                                                    
    fill_in "Description", :with => "An event that occurs once and never repeats..."                   
    fill_in "Start Date", :with => "2011-07-18"                                                        
    fill_in "Start Time", :with => "1:00pm"                                                            
    fill_in "End Date", :with => "2011-07-18"                                                          
    fill_in "End Time", :with => "3:00pm"                                                              
    uncheck "All Day"                                                                                  
    click_on "Create Event"                                                                            
  end                                                                                                  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason setting config.cache_classes to true in my environments/test.rb made it work as expected. Not sure why.